# How can I subscribe to multiple HTTP requests in Angular 6 (with rxjs 6) and ensure that all requests are made even one of them throws an error

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs6

I have three observables, returned by get() method of HttpClient. I use forkJoin operator in order to get a signal when all petitions have ended.

```
const responses = [
  this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/articles').pipe(
    map( data => this.articles = data ),
    catchError( err => throwError("Can't get the articles list") )
  ),
  this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/notas').pipe(
    map( data => this.news = data ),
    catchError( err => throwError("Can't get the news list") )
  ),
  this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users').pipe(
    map( data => this.users = data ),
    catchError( err => throwError("Can't get the users list") )
  )
];

forkJoin(responses).pipe(
  catchError( err => throwError(err) )
).subscribe(
  response => console.log('All data loaded')
);
```

If the first HTTP request throws an error, the other HTTP requests are made, but the corresponding callbacks are not executed. I read on [rxjs docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin) "If any input Observable errors at some point, forkJoin will error as well and all other Observables will be immediately unsubscribed.". So I guess that my forkJoin is working as it's expected, but then I'm not getting the funcionality I need.

So: how do I ensure, with forkJoin or any equivalent method, that all requests are made and all callbacks are executed, even when one of them throws an error?

Comment: Seems like promises might be best here

Comment: @inorganik But this seems like a typical scenario to me, and the HttpClient service works with observables. I'm hoping that there's a way of doing this with observables.

Comment: @inorganik How would you use promises to get what I need? Promise.all() also stops if any request fail.

Comment: Seems like if you are counting on requests throwing errors so often you are architecting your app wrong. If it's an empty response, or 401, set it up so the request doesn't error. Usually only 400, 404, or 500 should cause your request to error, and that should rarely happen in your app

Comment: I'm not counting on errors so often, I just want to manage the errors that an external API (not my app) may throw.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally managed it creating a custom observable that emits when all inner observables have either emitted or thrown error:

```
  public allRequests(requests: Observable<any>[]): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(
      observer => {
        requests.forEach((request, i) => {
          request.subscribe(
            resp => {
              emitOnLast(i);
            },
            err => {
              emitOnLast(i);
              console.error(err);
            }
          );
          const emitOnLast = (n: number) => {
            if (n === requests.length - 1) {
              observer.next(this.msg);
            }
          };
        });
      }
    );
  }
```